Embedded door hinges - how to remove

Has anyone seen this type of door hinge that's semi-embedded into the door frame?
I'm in process of switching these hinges out for more modern ones, but not sure how I can remove this.
I can't tell if its covered by paint or a layer of something..
[EDIT]
I added more pictures and also of another door. I realize several of my closets and doors are like this. I think its somehow slotted into the door frame. But if I strip away the paint, I might be able to expose the screws.



Paint.  Someone was just lazy.

To find the screws will need paint stripper.  Either chemical or mechanical, a wire brush on an angle grinder.

A picture of the other side of the hinge with the door closed, with the angle shooting a bit of the top of the hinge, not straight down from the top, just so the face and the top can be seen in the same picture. I have an idea the hinge was covered in putty to smooth out the area then painted. It looks like I see a little ridge suggesting that is the case.

I added more pictures above, thanks for taking a look. Several of my closets and door frames are like this so I feel there's a slot into the frame somehow. If I strip away the paint, I  might be able to expose the screws.

It appears to be a thick coating of paint.  In which case, something sharp such as a chisel would probably lift one end.  And the rest will probably peel off.
If that doesn't work then

Clear up the screw-holes with anything sharp such as knife, nail or screwdriver.
And using a sharp knife, trace the outline of the hinge to cut the paint around the hinge.
After removing the screws, you may have to pry off the hinge with a chisel (carefully).


Thanks for the suggestions, will definitely give that a go! I added more pictures above, I think its somehow slotted into the frame. But if I can scrape away the paint, I might be able to expose the screw holes..
